# Inequality of the $L_p$ spaces

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces

Assume we have $1\leq p<q<\infty$. How can I show that $L_p(\mathbb{R})\neq L_q(\mathbb{R})$?

I suppose the easiest way would be to show that neither is a subset of the other, but how would I get started on that?

Comment: Would this be useful? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/383003/lebesgue-integrable-function-and-square-integrable-functions

Comment: It suffices to show that just one is not contained in the other. Look at $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+|x|^s}$ for some $s>0$. Show that you can force it to be in one $L$ space but not the other.

Comment: A better exercise would be to show neither is contained in the other

Answer (score 1):

Note $L^q(\mathbb{R})\subset L^p(\mathbb{R})$. Let 
$$ f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} \frac{1}{x^\alpha}&\text{ if }x\in(0,1)\\0&\text{ else}\end{array}\right. $$
where $\alpha=\frac{p+q}{2pq}$. Clearly
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}}|f|^pdx=\int_0^1\frac{1}{x^\frac{p+q}{2q}}dx<\infty$$
and 
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}}|f|^qdx=\int_0^1\frac{1}{x^\frac{p+q}{2p}}dx=\infty. $$
So $L^q(\mathbb{R})\not=L^p(\mathbb{R})$.